# DOM is not updating with updated content in Vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, vuex, dom-events

I am a creating an application in Vue. I am getting an issue on showing the updating content, coming through the event bus. I also tried to use vuex for local content but it is still showing same issue.

Content is in Array format having some objects, creating through some form inputs.

Console is showing the updated content but Updated content is not showing on DOM.

Let me add some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me??

Let me add some code using in my project. I am using Vue Materail in code.

**Template 1**

```
<md-select v-model="bedroom" name="bedroom" id="bedroom" @md-selected="getBedVal('bedroom', 10)">
                            <md-option value="1">1</md-option>
                            <md-option value="2">2</md-option>
                            <md-option value="3">3</md-option>
                            <md-option value="4">4</md-option>
                            <md-option value="5">5</md-option>
                            <md-option value="6">6</md-option>
                            <md-option value="7">7</md-option>
                            <md-option value="8">8</md-option>
                            <md-option value="9">9</md-option>
                            <md-option value="10">10</md-option>

                        </md-select>
```

**Component 1:-**

```js
methods: {
    ServiceInfoFun: function(obj){
      var existingIds = this.getServiceInfo.map((obj) => obj.servicename);
      if (!existingIds.includes(obj.servicename)) {
        this.getServiceInfo.push(obj);
          bus.$emit('extraservice', this.getServiceInfo);
          //this.$store.dispatch('serviceListAction', this.getServiceInfo)
      } else {
        this.getServiceInfo.forEach((element, index) => {
          if (element.servicename === obj.servicename) {
              this.getServiceInfo[index] = obj;
              // this.$store.dispatch('serviceListAction', this.getServiceInfo); 
              bus.$emit('extraservice', this.getServiceInfo);
          };
        });
      };
    },
    getBedVal: function(name, price){ 
      var obj = {
        servicename: name,
        serviceprice: price * this.bedroom,
        serviceqty : this.bedroom
      }
       this.ServiceInfoFun(obj);
    },
  }
```

**Template 2**

```
{{ serviceInfo }}
```

**Component 2:**

```js
  created(){
    bus.$on('extraservice', (data) => {
        this.serviceInfo = data;
        console.log(this.serviceInfo);
  },
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code. It is a pain to help you without the running code that throw this error

Comment: ok .. Let me add some code.

Comment: I added some line of code, My friend.

Comment: Can you post the template that should renders the code too ? I try to solve it

Comment: I also add template in code. Please have a look.

Comment: Did you declare `serviceInfo` inside the data function ? Only variable declared inside it are reactive

Comment: Yes, My friend. 

https://prnt.sc/s29b6j

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212012/discussion-between-lyokolux-and-vick-sain).

Comment: ok @Lyokolux.. Let's discuss.

Comment: @Lyokolux Did you get any solution of it or any reason why it is not updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your data is loaded *after* the DOM is loaded, since it is nested it won't be reactive so you can't expect it to update.

You have a few options:

1) put a v-if somewhere which prevents the DOM from loading before your data is in place.

2) Manually force a reload, my preferred method is by giving a key and changing the key. See here for a detailed example: https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/

NOTE: Just to elaborate, if you are getting your data in PROPS then it comes fairly early otoh if is in some lifecycle say "created" then the DOM will be loading first for sure.

Comment: Hi @Michael, It is not working .. Can you please create an example?

Comment: I would need to see your template 2 to be more specific, is that where the data is not being updated?

Comment: Hi @Michael, In template 2, I used this {{ serviceInfo }} and get the emited data on create.
created(){
    bus.$on('extraservice', (data) => {
        this.serviceInfo = data;
        console.log(this.serviceInfo);
  },

Comment: so put a key on the surrounding element and change (+1) inside the function above.

Comment: I make a counter and modified it, on getting the data from other component. Now it working fine. Thank You. You are a genius . Thanks again. Love you. :)

Comment: sure, please mark my answer as correct if it solved your issue. Thanks